# Favicon: how to get it right for all modern common platforms?

Tags: css, html, favicon

The famous "favicon" for websites comes in many different variants, file formats and resolutions nowadays, to support the needs for multiple versions of different operating systems.

There are many sites to generate all required icon files along with the corresponding <head> code. For example: [favicomatic.com](http://favicomatic.com), [faviconit.com](http://faviconit.com), [favicon.ml](https://favicon.ml), [realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net) (there are many more of course). However they all seem to generate different formats, or different <head> code, yet none of them seems to get it 100% right.

For example, with the icons and <head> code they all produce, Firefox (latest versions) will show a **low res icon on high res displays** (e.g. Retina).

I noticed if you *remove* the 16x16 icon reference from the <head> section, e.g.
`<link rel='icon' type='image/png' sizes='16x16' href='favicon-16x16.png'`
Then it looks right. But I guess that line is supposed to be there for a reason?

And I wonder about the differences. Some include the Windows tile icons (such as `<meta name='msapplication-square150x150logo' content='mstile-150x150.png'>`) within the <head> section, some put that in a separate `browserconfig.xml` file to which they refer from <head>, some do both.

Some use `apple-touch-icon` icons, some use `apple-touch-icon-precomposed`.

Some generate an `android-chrome-512x512.png` icon to which they refer from a separate `manifest.json` file, some don't.

Now there are many guidelines and instructions for this, most are contradicting and none are complete, as far as I can tell.

Is there a clear standard or set of rules for this, as to what icons and <head> references to include nowadays, to **correctly** support all modern browsers on major platforms? That is, to get the most suitable or best resolution icons everywhere?

P.S. I know similar questions have been asked before. I looked through many of them, none had a definitive answer, or they seemed to lack some of the points mentioned above.

Comment: @VXp with Firefox (all recent versions) the output generated by realfavicongenerator.net will show a low res icon on high res / retina screens.

Comment: @VXp Here's a [screenshot example](https://i.imgur.com/ZX1qp73.png) of an icon set generated by realfavicongenerator.net and also the difference when I remove the 16x16 reference manually (which I don't understand why it causes any problems in the first place). This is what it looks like on my macbook pro with retina screen, using latest Firefox and Chrome.
Vivaldi also looks bad (like Firefox). Safari shows no favicon.